# How can I place a geo-referenced SVG over an openlayers map (not as image)

Tags: svg, openlayers, openlayers-6

How can I place a complex SVG image (with css-styles!) geo-referenced over an openlayers map so that the document's CSS styles are used with rendering the SVG.

A regular ImageLayer does a fine job of showing the georeferenced svg on the map *as an image*. But because it is an image, the CSS of the document has no effect on the rendered SVG

The [SVG Layer example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/svg-layer.html) on the other hand places the SVG into the DOM and makes it react to the document's CSS and reacts when you change the CSS. But it always maps the SVG over the whole planet and seems to hide any layer I place under it.

To give you an idea of the use case: we have an externally generated SVG with several 'groups or layers' in it representing different aspects of infrastructure. This svg has to be put correctly over a map (like we can do with the imagelayer), but we want to be able to selectively show/hide the different 'groups or layers' that are *within the SVG*.

I guess in the end we would be needing something similar to [ol/layer/Image/ImageLayer](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Image-ImageLayer.html) to happen in the SVG-layer example.

Any suggestions about how to approach this would be very welcome, but working code is also OK ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example the image width is 360 degrees and the center is at [0, 0].  For a smaller extent you would need to use the appropriate width and adjust the center used in the transform https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-poitras-i1qyb?file=/main.js  Use an opacity setting to avoid completely hiding the base layer.